# Alternatives to Avenza Maps

Tags: software-recommendations, geospatial-pdf, avenza

I enjoyed Avenza Maps until recently...

After their recent move to a subscription model, I am in the market for a comparable app.

Feature requirements:

1. Load Geospatial PDFs
2. Capture photos along point data
3. Does not have to be free, one-off fees qualify (up to 100$).
4. Platform is iOS, Android if applicable.

Comment: I think your question would be more on-topic (with work) on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Since this relates to software very specific to the gis community, I would rather keep it here. Geospatial PDFs are not widely known...

Comment: Then as much as possible can you try to adhere to their [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) even though you are posting here.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37396/alternative-to-avenza-pdf-maps)  ([one answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/37399/10546) so far) and [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217224/seeking-alternatives-to-avenza-pdf-maps-app) (deleted by its asker).

Comment: There is no answer on the platform...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run an older version of the software if updates and support aren't required. There are quite a few websites that host .APK installers for legacy versions of apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can still have unlimited PDFs with the Avenza app for 30$ a year. It's obviously not an one-off thing, but it's pretty close to your 100$ price range over a few years...